# Wordpress multi user - create a static folder for individual user

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I've several blog hosting under Wordpress Multisite
http:// yourdomain.com/
http:// yourdomain.com/user1/
http:// yourdomain.com/user2/

The Wordpress root is installed under

**/var/host/yourdomain.com/public/**

However, i would like to create a static html folder to include some static html files 
http:// yourdomain.com/user1/STATIC_FOLDER/css/ *.*
http:// yourdomain.com/user1/STATIC_FOLDER/images/ *.*
http:// yourdomain.com/user1/STATIC_FOLDER/index.html

I've also created a sub folders to allow user to FTP directly
/var/host/yourdomain.com/public/user1/STATIC_FOLDER/ *.*

Would somebody be able to advise me on the editing of htaccess? or recommend any plugins, or workaround to enable this? appreciate any help thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official guide to install a MU

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

However the folder layout you suggest doesn't work this way.
You can do this but your static folders will have to be placed in the `blog.dir`
You could even consider that users upload these files with the normal uploader.

Comment: i though of tweaking the htaccess to expose the folder directly when url is hitted, is there any way to tweak the htaccess to allow viewing of folders/files directly? or escape those i suggested not to enter the default .php handler?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way for this...

Basically i've edited the htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^user1/STATIC_FOLDER/(.*)$    user1/STATIC_FOLDER/$1   [NC,L]
```

First i've to understand how to edit htaccess, here's a good tutorial
 http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

The "$1" in the substitution tells Apache to put whatever matched the earlier bracketed ()  pattern into the URL at this point

For Regular Expression here's a good tips - Regex for htaccess...

- . (any character)
- * (zero of more of the preceding)
- + (one or more of the preceding)
- {} (minimum to maximum quantifier)
- ? (ungreedy modifier)
- ! (at start of string means "negative pattern")
- ^ (start of string, or "negative" if at the start of a range)
- $ (end of string)
- [] (match any of contents)
- - (range if used between square brackets)
- () (group, backreferenced group)
- | (alternative, or)
- \ (the escape character itself)